# Concatenate binary numbers of different lengths

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

So I have 3 numbers. One is a `char`, and the other two are `int16_t` (also known as `short`s, but according to a table I found shorts won't reliably be 16 bits).

I'd like to concatenate them together. So say that the values of them were:

`10010001`

`1111111111111101`

`1001011010110101`

I'd like to end up with a `long long` containing:

`1001000111111111111111011001011010110101000000000000000000000000`

Using some solutions I've found online, I came up with this:

```
long long result;
result = num1;
result = (result << 8) | num2;
result = (result << 24) | num3;
```

But it doesn't work; it gives me very odd numbers when it's decoded.

In case there's a problem with my decoding code, here it is:

```
char num1 = num & 0xff;
int16_t num2 = num << 8 & 0xffff;
int16_t num3 = num << 24 & 0xffff;
```

What's going on here? I suspect it has to do with the size of a `long long`, but I can't quite wrap my head around it and I want room for more numbers in it later.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get the correct bit-pattern as you requested, you shoud use:

```
result = num1;
result = (result << 16) | num2;
result = (result << 16) | num3; 
result<<=24;
```

This will yield the exact bit pattern that you requested, 24 bits at the lsb-end left 0:

```
1001000111111111111111011001011010110101000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 3):

For that last shift, you should only be shifting by 16, not by 24.  24 is the current length of your binary string, after the combination of num1 and num2.  You need to make room for num3, which is 16 bits, so shift left by 16.

**Edit:**

Just realized the first shift is wrong too.  That should be 16 also, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are overflowing the value that can be stored in long. You can use a arbitrary precison library to store the big number like the [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: I'll look into that, but I might think about a different approach (putting the numbers on the right instead of the left?) because plain numbers are the fastest.

Comment: He's using `long long`, not `long`.  `long long` can store at least 64 bits, he only needs 40.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you are doing, I would use:

```
result = num1;
result = (result << 16) | num2;
result = (result << 16) | num3;

num1out = (result >> 32) & 0xff;
num2out = (result >> 16) & 0xffff;
num3out = result & 0xffff;
```

The left shift during building is by the width of the next number to insert. The right shift on extraction is by the total number of bits the field was left shifted during building.

I have tested the above code. long long is wide enough for this task with the g++ compiler, and I believe many others.