# Bitwise Concatenation

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I have the following:

```
char *pointer = decimal_to_binary(192) // yields 11000000
char *pointer2 = decimal_to_binary(168) // yields 10101000
```

I am trying to concat them into:

```
1100000010101000
```

I was referencing: [Concatenate binary numbers of different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222374/concatenate-binary-numbers-of-different-lengths) and am currently using:

```
unsigned long pointer3 = (*pointer << 16) | *pointer2;
```

which gives the output:

```
1100010000000000110001
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: considering a 32 big machine, did you try `(*pointer << 32) | *pointer2`

Comment: Are you sure there's the last 0 on the result you want? If all you want is to concat both pointers it seems the last 0 is in excess...

Comment: Fixed. thanks Claudio.

Comment: Your code does not even compile

Comment: I think the question was a little confusing... did you want to concatenate a string which represents the binary number or the bits themselves (an integer)? The title "bitwise concatenation" made me think you wanted the operation on a number and you just had some syntax errors, but after @JonathanLeffler's answer I suspect you want to just concatenate the strings representing the binary numbers... What is the real focus?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first you shouldn't initialize a pointer with an integer; the compiler will probably warn you like this:

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   char* pointer1 = 0xc0;
```

If you're not familiar with hexadecimal notation, please refer to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal); you'll see converting from binary to hex is much more straightforward than from decimal to hex, for instance.

If you want to represent these 8-bit numbers you could assign them directly to `unsigned char` variables, like I did down here (paste this code in a file "test.c", for example):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  unsigned char num1 = 0xc0; /* Same as binary 11000000 in hex */
  unsigned char num2 = 0xa8; /* Same as binary 10101000 in hex */

  unsigned long result = (num1 << 8) | num2;
  printf("0x%x\n", result);
}
```

You can compile this with `gcc -o test test.c`, which outputs this when run: `0xc0a8` (this is the same as 1100000010101000).

If you assign the numbers to pointers like you did, you'll likely get a "segmentation fault" or "access violation" when you try to dereference them with `*pointer` and `*pointer2`, because that means you want the value stored at the pointer address, which probably doesn't lie in your program address space.

Since `result` is a long (32-bit), it can surely hold your 16-bit number just fine, but `num1` and `num2` have to be `unsigned char`, so when you left shift and OR them it doesn't make the whole thing negative - in a signed binary number the leftmost bit set to 1 means it is a negative number, so if you use a plain `char` instead it will sign extend the 32-bit result so it remains negative: `0xffffffa8`

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how you print anything, which makes it difficult to interpret your question.  However, this statement is irretrievably broken in that it does nothing to concatenate the strings pointed at by `pointer` and `pointer2`:

```
unsigned long pointer3 = (*pointer << 16) | *pointer2;
```

This takes the first character that `pointer` points at (a `1`) and shifts the value left 16 bits, and then adds (ors) in the first character that `pointer2` points at (another `1`), and assigns the integer thus format to the misnamed `pointer3`.  Thus, it gets the value:

```
pointer3 = 0x00310031;
```

The question takes some interpretation, but making some plausible (but not necessarily accurate) assumptions, this code might do what you're after:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *decimal_to_binary(unsigned char byte)
{
    char *result = malloc(9);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        char *digit = result;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            *digit++ = ((byte >> (7 - i)) & 0x01) + '0';
        *digit = '\0';
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *pointer1 = decimal_to_binary(192);
    char *pointer2 = decimal_to_binary(168);
    char  concatenated[17];
    unsigned long pointer3 = (*pointer1 << 16) | *pointer2;

    strcpy(&concatenated[0], pointer1);
    strcpy(&concatenated[8], pointer2);

    printf("P1 = <<%s>>; P2 = <<%s>>; P3 = 0x%08lX; C = <<%s>>\n",
           pointer1, pointer2, pointer3, concatenated);

    free(pointer1);
    free(pointer2);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
P1 = <<11000000>>; P2 = <<10101000>>; P3 = 0x00310031; C = <<1100000010101000>>
```

Note that the code using `decimal_to_binary()` does not take care to avoid (mis)using null pointers.  The design of `decimal_to_binary()` is also less than stellar; those `free()` calls are easily forgotten.  A better design would be:

```
void decimal_to_binary(unsigned char byte, char buffer[9]);
```

where the calling code provides the buffer into which the binary output is written.  There are also other ways of writing the loop in `decimal_to_binary()`; some might even be more efficient than the one chosen here.

Comment: here you have used strcpy.. why are you making them strings...then there is no meaning of doing all this i think....just convert them to string and join them... i think we must use bitwise operator for doing this

Comment: Well, your code has `char *pointer = decimal_to_binary(192);`, so I presume that `decimal_to_binary()` is returning a `char *`, which normally means `a string`.  If you had `unsigned char number1 = decimal_to_binary(192);` (which could eliminate the function call and be written `unsigned char number1 = 192;`), and similarly for `unsigned number2 = 168;`, then you could combine them with `unsigned short number3 = (number1 << 8) | number2;`.  If you want good answers, provide a good SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) which shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: This isn't my que. i am just answering it.
and if you only want to print the binary then why to use bitwise operation thats what i am asking... i thought we should concatenate those two number and then prints its binary value

Comment: @umang2203: oh, sorry — didn't look carefully enough to notice you are a co-answerer.  The question is confused.  I took one way of looking at the question, based on the `char *` types used.  You're taking an alternative viewpoint, based on the mention of bitwise operations.  Your choice may well be better than mine — the question certainly should be written better to make it clearer what's really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

First only assign one number in pointer like 
`unsigned long pointer3 = *pointer;`
after this left shift this `pointer3` 16 times.
`pinter3=pointer3<<16;`
`pointer3=pointer3|*pointer2;`

this will work i think

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't help at all; the net result is the same as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to shift by 16 as you are doing in

```
unsigned long pointer3 = (*pointer << 16) | *pointer2;
```

*pointer* only needs to be shifted by 8.
Following code will achieve what you are trying to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_binary(int num) {
    short rem[16] = {0};
    for (short i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
        rem[16-i] = num%2;
        num = num >> 1;
    }
    for (short int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%d", rem[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {

    unsigned char num1 = 192;
    unsigned char num2 = 168;
    int num3 = 0;
    num3 = (num1 << 8) | num2;
    printf("first number: %d\n", num1);
    print_binary(num1);

    printf("second number: %d\n", num2);
    print_binary(num2);

    printf("The number is %d\n", num3);
    print_binary(num3);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one looks easy to understand)

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    using namespace std;



    int main()
    {
    int a = 32; // 100000
    int b = 5; // 101
    int step=0;
    int siz=0;
    while(1){
    if(pow(2,step) < b){
    step++;
    continue;
    }
    else{
    siz = step;
    break;
    }

    }
    a = a<<siz;
    a = a | b;
    cout<<a;
    }
```

Comment: This answer is sloppy, unclear and hard to understand.